# Simulate a link click in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a link that redirects to a chat page when clicked. Now, I want to redirect to that page from inside a coffeescript code. How can I simulate the link below(with parameters) to have the same effect as clicking it?

```
<%= link_to "Send", "#", class: "chat",
           "data-sender" => current_user.id, "data-receiver" => user.id 
%>
```

Comment: show your coffescript file

Comment: how about triggering click event on your a link?

Comment: App.broadcast = App.cable.subscriptions.create "BroadcastChannel",
      connected: ->

      disconnected: ->

     received: (data) ->
       sender_id = data.sender
       reciever_id = data.receiver



       $('.chat').click(sender: sender_id, receiver: receiver_id)


   .
   .
   .

Comment: Hi, Can you show me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you first should update the question with your action cable related updates that is in the comment section.

Some thing like this should work.

```
received: (data) ->
  sender_id = data.sender
  reciever_id = data.receiver
  link = $('a.chat')

  link.attr('data-sender', sender_id)      # To set data attributes for the link
  link.attr('data-receiver', receiver_id)
  link.trigger('click')                    # Triggering a click so that the rest of the code can take over
```

What I don't know is how your application may work.

What I am trying to do is to update the data attributes or the link to the values obtained from action cable and then trigger a click event on the link so that the rest of the code in your app can take over.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I wanted though it still is not working for me.

Comment: Does it give an error? Are you sure the `received` is fired?

Comment: Yes, it is fired. your code works if I comment out the two 'link.data' lines

Comment: What is your jQuery version? Can you try some thing like `link.attr('data-sender', sender_id)` and see if it works?

Comment: Perfect!. Thanks A lot. I have accepted your answer

Comment: Great, I will update the answer. The `$(...).data` is supposed to be a short cut for the other.